# Difference in static and class method in dart

Tags: dart

I am little new to dart. I am trying to understand the difference between these two methods. Are both methods different or same? Where should I use one above another? Can someone explain it to me?

```
class A {
  A.executor1() {
    print('executor one is called');
  }

  static executor2() {
    print('executor two is called');
  }
}
```

Meanwhile neither of the method call is required to make a new instance? both are called using the class name.

```
void main() {
  A.executor1(); // Will print "executor one is called"
  A.executor2(); // Will print "executor two is called"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A.executor1()` is a named constructor. `static executor2()` is a static method.

With an IDE (or dartpad.dev) you can see the different return types when you are placing the cursor over each `method`:

```
void main() {
  A.executor1(); // (new) A A.executor1()
  A.executor2(); // dynamic executor2()
}
```

Comment: One can go to this link to better understand it. https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#named-constructors

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods can be called without creating an instance of the class. `executor1` will have access to `this` and so on because it's attached to an actual instance, but `static` methods will not because they aren't attached to anything.

Consider (in Javascript):

```js
class Bicycle {
  static numWheels = 2;
  
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  static numberOfWheels() {
    console.log(`Every bike has ${this.numWheels} wheels.`);
  }
  
  myColor() {
    console.log(`This bike is ${this.color}.`);
  }
}

// property of an instance
new Bicycle('red').myColor();

// available for anyone!
Bicycle.numberOfWheels();
```

Comment: I understand the difference between static method and the instance method. Here case is different, None of them is required to have the instance of the class. Where executor1 will point, if instance has not been created?

Comment: It looks like `A.executor1() {...}` is the same as defining `static executor1() {...}`, so they are the same. An instance method would be `executor1() {...}`.